# Why is Resultant so slow?

Tags: polynomials

I need to calculate the discriminant of a polynomial $f$

```
f=(-1+a)^3 (-776887+6874047 a-27016044 a^2+61683852 a^3-89995170 a^4+87469410 a^5-57357788 a^6+24894300 a^7-6591327 a^8+816631 a^9)+(-1+a)^3 (-70993+1896501 a-11839806 a^2+35821722 a^3-63596496 a^4+71428356 a^5-51882626 a^6+23934390 a^7-6506655 a^8+816631 a^9) x+(-1+a)^2 (840677-9542810 a+47207997 a^2-135031578 a^3+248395929 a^4-308650374 a^5+264614389 a^6-156310810 a^7+61574754 a^8-14731244 a^9+1633262 a^10) x^2+(-1+a)^2 (129099-2799402 a+19387209 a^2-67207288 a^3+136742323 a^4-174982152 a^5+144394795 a^6-76037770 a^7+24129804 a^8-3977900 a^9+221474 a^10) x^3+(894208-7149222 a+20073528 a^2-2054774 a^3-144920982 a^4+478602414 a^5-857407667 a^6+1005151044 a^7-810928698 a^8+451582962 a^9-167568090 a^10+37614714 a^11-3889329 a^12) x^4+(178880-2446308 a+9063762 a^2+3790466 a^3-126891966 a^4+457212222 a^5-903469075 a^6+1153113090 a^7-995654634 a^8+582660372 a^9-223193202 a^10+50937618 a^11-5301117 a^12) x^5+(-4000394+46952040 a-259388316 a^2+887227366 a^3-2084343390 a^4+3531378276 a^5-4412512094 a^6+4089615420 a^7-2787965547 a^8+1363301874 a^9-454078080 a^10+92544774 a^11-8734838 a^12) x^6+(3708350-37891848 a+174175842 a^2-467358022 a^3+797163480 a^4-883749474 a^5+623488238 a^6-261712422 a^7+64485129 a^8-27300342 a^9+24126594 a^10-10978182 a^11+1839748 a^12) x^7+(-3971582+46662942 a-240848997 a^2+717168814 a^3-1346170320 a^4+1602458772 a^5-1072434353 a^6+87218892 a^7+578439381 a^8-604029018 a^9+312548709 a^10-87797676 a^11+10752260 a^12) x^8+(3725402-42155988 a+220308483 a^2-726027694 a^3+1719892446 a^4-3109295520 a^5+4359268237 a^6-4686999546 a^7+3761660931 a^8-2165592088 a^9+841641801 a^10-197679852 a^11+21252562 a^12) x^9+(-3962432+21725790 a+14194032 a^2-470287610 a^3+1968609555 a^4-4560656610 a^5+6945295020 a^6-7361612814 a^7+5516570493 a^8-2886746578 a^9+1008740706 a^10-212268276 a^11+20397806 a^12) x^10+(3729152-28395528 a+93238374 a^2-172509208 a^3+212854815 a^4-236731740 a^5+287816964 a^6-271566798 a^7+105820767 a^8+69384232 a^9-102655314 a^10+46925442 a^11-7912238 a^12) x^11+(8390713-101561976 a+561146283 a^2-1846399386 a^3+3973833123 a^4-5777524302 a^5+5605553833 a^6-3320970108 a^7+734319906 a^8+511501480 a^9-502609110 a^10+179556210 a^11-25238583 a^12) x^12+(-15449653+172514268 a-896985957 a^2+2873154826 a^3-6370549065 a^4+10437946374 a^5-13111200467 a^6+12777994458 a^7-9541017948 a^8+5259792966 a^9-2004579318 a^10+468995046 a^11-50617447 a^12) x^13+(15406435-172028070 a+830834820 a^2-2249895142 a^3+3628529652 a^4-3161659950 a^5+285093920 a^6+2873565738 a^7-3827808222 a^8+2621528706 a^9-1059772530 a^10+239529654 a^11-23299307 a^12) x^14+(-15423487+178881540 a-928487742 a^2+2890145104 a^3-6053988300 a^4+9024650346 a^5-9802567880 a^6+7720516710 a^7-4222937568 a^8+1420856432 a^9-180967062 a^10-45503178 a^11+14852289 a^12) x^15+(15418912-129228396 a+449732580 a^2-801737812 a^3+675024942 a^4-86199144 a^5+68598089 a^6-1223702814 a^7+2442674985 a^8-2383964134 a^9+1326814152 a^10-407760984 a^11+54302180 a^12) x^16+(-15418912+109072176 a-245960688 a^2-203921432 a^3+2513390106 a^4-7112007762 a^5+11998820905 a^6-13902109860 a^7+11499587169 a^8-6740526806 a^9+2668761756 a^10-639711024 a^11+69988060 a^12) x^17+(-1051948+40039248 a-328540632 a^2+1275612164 a^3-2796000582 a^4+3513412704 a^5-1991744464 a^6-858793800 a^7+2492460327 a^8-2040361980 a^9+866912220 a^10-186909600 a^11+14963403 a^12) x^18+(24115188-280341120 a+1512347580 a^2-4959184460 a^3+10963877658 a^4-17153784186 a^5+19342782724 a^6-15617528364 a^7+8690120601 a^8-3002662558 a^9+441113808 a^10+64981404 a^11-25823695 a^12) x^19+(-31145316+351004188 a-1758557610 a^2+5202646484 a^3-10238342409 a^4+14454079644 a^5-15626544412 a^6+13707289008 a^7-9995415249 a^8+5834636422 a^9-2478492495 a^10+660132744 a^11-81282143 a^12) x^20+(31122188-356398320 a+1779577506 a^2-5111761476 a^3+9252580695 a^4-10638378600 a^5+6907818726 a^6-574805004 a^7-3493137987 a^8+3569762950 a^9-1792882989 a^10+481587204 a^11-55052385 a^12) x^21+(-31127872+312597612 a-1440131112 a^2+4074175372 a^3-8016733323 a^4+11785685544 a^5-13470810008 a^6+12048214386 a^7-8181326178 a^8+3949448958 a^9-1213843434 a^10+191326584 a^11-7479121 a^12) x^22+(31127872-250368984 a+826995180 a^2-1287070012 a^3+334943907 a^4+2441424288 a^5-5036533654 a^6+4994979288 a^7-2610520122 a^8+344334270 a^9+411060840 a^10-245134242 a^11+44647321 a^12) x^23+(-18774727+137483916 a-356464152 a^2+120693052 a^3+1604383635 a^4-4952273562 a^5+8279201519 a^6-9536183676 a^7+8101877028 a^8-5060477142 a^9+2191735509 a^10-581788692 a^11+70578412 a^12) x^24+(-8994473+125348592 a-767239230 a^2+2676501776 a^3-5859484161 a^4+8285722386 a^5-7303496577 a^6+3238794768 a^7+491347416 a^8-1598160210 a^9+954830079 a^10-263295936 a^11+28251042 a^12) x^25+(27932795-323396112 a+1690680894 a^2-5310480698 a^3+11262944364 a^4-17147569392 a^5+19324692342 a^6-16218810378 a^7+9939590565 a^8-4213230216 a^9+1096469868 a^10-126514380 a^11-2290116 a^12) x^26+(-31447859+361310208 a-1813105128 a^2+5282867216 a^3-9993566700 a^4+13046286180 a^5-12339859474 a^6+8976605490 a^7-5424861117 a^8+2847811772 a^9-1210805526 a^10+345301446 a^11-46627564 a^12) x^27+(31440656-341668302 a+1677134820 a^2-4889457854 a^3+9337036209 a^4-12097090854 a^5+10532399540 a^6-5636490864 a^7+1084733592 a^8+826673840 a^9-740717796 a^10+248489778 a^11-32538061 a^12) x^28+(-31440656+292188948 a-1251023826 a^2+3296229350 a^3-6059445369 a^4+8380029096 a^5-9131415164 a^6+7959542616 a^7-5430924102 a^8+2738023204 a^9-927106890 a^10+178848546 a^11-13365785 a^12) x^29+(26499398-226736280 a+837766188 a^2-1702261810 a^3+1923802575 a^4-790768692 a^5-984870488 a^6+1899202476 a^7-1469171376 a^8+558767836 a^9-36690636 a^10-48415626 a^11+13002579 a^12) x^30+(-11203010+93660552 a-322592118 a^2+557096922 a^3-364642737 a^4-454355508 a^5+1446042288 a^6-1986958464 a^7+1864663992 a^8-1271875716 a^9+599933886 a^10-172331466 a^11+22407587 a^12) x^31+(-5271886+67827654 a-384789249 a^2+1273415886 a^3-2726817306 a^4+3917432364 a^5-3726626871 a^6+2142374802 a^7-456505653 a^8-292112670 a^9+265312560 a^10-84345204 a^11+9993253 a^12) x^32+(12097546-141972252 a+734616267 a^2-2245861782 a^3+4583829450 a^4-6685245696 a^5+7245341489 a^6-5914174782 a^7+3587151963 a^8-1547783120 a^9+434790060 a^10-65650176 a^11+2934313 a^12) x^33+(-12803440+145682070 a-736804680 a^2+2181695766 a^3-4200882909 a^4+5546799954 a^5-5200805278 a^6+3582498618 a^7-1895638152 a^8+810117232 a^9-280905258 a^10+69880824 a^11-8802939 a^12) x^34+(12803440-132647424 a+639467454 a^2-1880142108 a^3+3710917287 a^4-5107569192 a^5+4940129896 a^6-3298370784 a^7+1431677586 a^8-331626088 a^9-2552478 a^10+21782028 a^11-3882417 a^12) x^35+(-11979897+113867568 a-499698201 a^2+1349841610 a^3-2525884350 a^4+3485764632 a^5-3657707002 a^6+2934445788 a^7-1773163245 a^8+779462888 a^9-233657325 a^10+41995818 a^11-3287260 a^12) x^36+(-1+a) (-8732381+76165447 a-294970340 a^2+665540442 a^3-967892598 a^4+956218842 a^5-666410116 a^6+341286224 a^7-136109941 a^8+44802887 a^9-11528656 a^10+1633262 a^11) x^37+(-1+a)^2 (-3931091+34131188 a-130837677 a^2+288883152 a^3-401955342 a^4+363366648 a^5-210859162 a^6+71786704 a^7-8910543 a^8-2487436 a^9+816631 a^10) x^38+(-1+a)^3 (-776887+6874047 a-27016044 a^2+61683852 a^3-89995170 a^4+87469410 a^5-57357788 a^6+24894300 a^7-6591327 a^8+816631 a^9) x^39;
```

It takes 55.674 seconds using `Resultant[f, D[f, x], x]; // AbsoluteTiming` while Maple takes only 2.953 seconds. It seems that they use the same algorithm from the documentation, but why is `Resultant` in *Mathematica* so slow?

__

In version 13.2, it's still a little slow on my machine (about 30 seconds).

Comment: Timings on my comp: Mathematica -- 58.2344 s, Maple -- 15.33 s.

Comment: According to a [recent meeting](https://youtu.be/EGgMuUYNAiU?t=81), there will be a significant improvement (10 to 100 times speed-ups) in version 13.2 (including `Resultant`) by using a new polynomial engine :)

Comment: On my machine (Mathematica 13.0, AMD Ryzen 9 5900X) this takes 12.88 seconds. I can not comment on Maple performance.

Comment: He will get a big boost in 13.2

Comment: Takes 23.9 seconds on my machine (Mathematica 13.2, Windows 10, AMD Threadripper 3960X)

Comment: 34.79 here and it is not cached. a^903. Wow.